# C++ Вернуть указатель на массив из фн

Tags: c++, указатели

Задача: нужно распарсить строку в формате "число;число;число;..." в обычный массив чисел.

Проблема, при попытке вернуть указатель, я так предполагаю, схлопывается область видимости, и данные превращаются в мусор,

Вопрос как правильно вернуть указатель, чтобы данные сохранились?

Вот код парсинга.

P.S - Сам код работает верно, пробегал в дебаге, на строчке с return, arr имеет нужные мне данные

```
int* SplitAndParseDigits(string digits)
{
    int digitsCount = GetCountOfDigits(digits);
    int* arr = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), digitsCount);

    string digitsymbols = "";
    int arrPtr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(digits.c_str()); i++)
    {
        if (digits[i] != ';')
            digitsymbols += digits[i];
        else
        {
            int parseResult =atoi(digitsymbols.c_str());
            arr[arrPtr] = parseResult;
            arr++;
            cout << parseResult;
            digitsymbols = "";
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Это C или C++? Если C++, то почему не `std::vector`?..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat c++, начал только учить, разбираюсь с указателями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в calloc неправильный параметры. первым аргументом должно быть количество, вторым размер. но это вроде не проблема и всё нормально будет.

вся проблема в `arr`. вы наверно хотели использовать `arrPtr` как индекс, но после `arr[arrPtr] = parseResult` вы увеличиваете сам указатель, а не индекс. ну то есть вы конечно же индекс увеличиваете, но потом передаете этот индекс в `return`. в `else` поменяйте так. вместо `arr++` укажите `arrPtr++`. и тогда будет возвращаться начало массива из функции.

Comment: уже нашёл проблему, вы были правы, по поводу arrPtr, а вот на счёт callock,к счастью, это не критично, т.к там в любом случае идёт лишь перемножение size и count.но тоже исправил)